# ssl перехват ключа

Tags: ssl

Народ, не совсем понимаю в чем сила алгоритма. Ключ то так или иначе передается по каналу, разве нельзя с трафиком перехватить ключ и потом юзать для чтения инфы?

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC   Сессионный ключ шифруется открытым ключем одной стороны и передается. Но знание открытого ключа не позволяет расшифровать данные. для этого требуется закрытый ключ по каналам связи не передающийся

Comment: Спс, почитал, стало понятнее... но теперь возникает вопрос, данные шифруются только в одну сторону от юзера к серверу? ведь только закрытый ключ может расшифровать их!

Comment: На самом деле все сложнее. асимметричное шифрование слишком медленное, что бы шифровать им весь трафик. данные шифруются каким нибудь AES. ключ для aes генерируется случайный на каждую сессию. в текущая версии ssl, если не ошибаюсь, половину ключа генерит клиент, половину сервер. после чего обмениваются этими половинами зашифрованными с помощью ассиметричного шифра. причем клиент так же генерит себе временные закрытый/открытый ключи, открытый отдает серверу и тот им шифрует ту половину ключа что шлет клиенту. а трафик потом в обе стороны шифруется одним и тем же AES ключем

Answer (score 2):

Там два ключа, один публичный - он передается открытыми каналами и служит только для шифровки.

Для дешифровки нужен второй - приватный ключ, который никуда не передается.